# Windows MSG structure conflicts with legacy project code struct MSG

Tags: c++, c

I was working on a legacy code which was running in Linux for more than 20 years.
It has 3 modules, which are handled by 3 different persons. I can change in one module only.

Now I got a task to build the same code in windows with minimal functionality.

For interprocess communications, a message structure is used. And it is conflicting with windows MSG structure.

This structure is getting used in other two modules also.

I don't want to rename the structure.
Is there any other way to resolve this?

code is a mix of C and C++.

Comment: Scope it with a namespace.

Comment: MSG structure is getting used in C files also. C doesn't have namespaces.

Comment: Wrapper functions and/or wrapper macros.

Comment: Is a project wide rename not possible or just inconvenient?

Comment: Yes, project is wide, module 'A' (on which I am working), module 'B' and module 'C'. B and C can have different versions. and different versions are handled by different persons.

Comment: @atulya: you misunderstood - the "is a project wide" was not a question that asks whever project is wide or small. The question was about "Is a project wide rename (..)", which means, "Is a rename over-the-whole-project (..)". Project-wide means over-the-whole-project.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. The One Definition Rule states that every name should have a unique definition, and your existing definition of `::MSG` doesn't match the `<Windows.h>` definition of `::MSG`.

Windows compilers don't tend to heavily enforce the ODR, so you might get away with it. You'd do generally do this by a hard separation between the two types. That is to say, in a .cpp file which includes `windows.h`, you cannot include any of your project headers and vice versa. The interface between the two parts must be defined in its own header, which relies on neither windows.h nor your own headers. (As a side benefit, you can then provide an alternative implementation of that .cpp file for Linux, which means your code doesn't get littered with `#ifdef WIN32`)

Comment: At first moment I thought about adding something like `#define MSG _myMSG` through project-wide command line compiler options.. `-DMSG=myMSG` or something very close I suppose. But then, it would also fire in `windows.h` so that's pointless unless this option is added only to non-windows-related code, which requires separating the code just like you wrote. So.. thumbs up for code separation first!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: You _can_ of course surround `#include windows.h` by `#define MSG_before MSG` and `#define MSG MSG_before #undef MSG_before`. But that means you can't call the related windows functions.

Comment: Thanks @MSalters, will give a try.